# May one perform the Seder out of order?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada

Does the order of the Seder matter? So long as each mitzvah is performed internally properly (i.e., at least a kezayis of matzah is eaten *at some point* in the Seder,  all the required sections of Maggid are recited *at some point* in the Seder, bentching is recited *at some point* after the meal, but not necessarily immediately before Hallel, etc.), may one rearrange the order in which these steps are performed, or is there a requirement that they be performed in the order described in the Mishnah (Pesachim ch. 10)?

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a substantively different order that allows for all the mitzvot to be performed properly.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.100a.6.1 (but it's not halacha lemaaseh because we don't follow R' Yosi)